# UILabel alpha causes text to fade as well

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is there a way such that I can set the alpha of a UILabel, but it doesn't fade out the text of the UILabel? Meaning just the background?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the text is a part of the label, if you set the alpha for the label the text fades appropriately. What you want is to set a `backgroundColor` with the appropriate alpha:

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have to create a background view (`UIView` will suffice), and put the `UILabel` on top (not as a subview, because the alpha value of the background view affects all of its subviews)